# Writing PDF files in C#

Tags: c#, api, pdf

I have been making C# software to write PDF files.

It's intended to be simple to use, compact, efficient and also reasonably simple to understand, maintain and extend as required.

The basic functionality supports multi-column layout with word-wrapping and justification, and the standard fonts.

Currently, additional classes support TrueType embedded font subsets and PNG graphics files. The complete set of source files is on [github here](https://github.com/georgebarwood/pdf).

For now, please review the main class, PdfWriter below. Questions:

(1) Any suggestions on useability ? How to document the public interface?

(2) Any suggestions on coding style or approach?

(3) Generally, how can I make it better?

```
using String = System.String; 
using IO = System.IO;
using Generic = System.Collections.Generic; 

namespace Pdf {

public class PdfWriter // class for writing PDF ( Portable Document Format ) files ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF ) .
{
  // Example usage
  public static void Example1() 
  {
    using( IO.FileStream fs = IO.File.Create( "Example1.pdf") )
    {
      PdfWriter w = new Pdf.PdfWriter(); 
      w.Title = "Hello World";
      w.Fonts = Pdf.StandardFontFamily.Times(); // Sets font family ( optional, default is Helvetica ).
      // Default PageLayout (width, height, margins) may be adjusted here.
      w.SetColumns( 3, 5 ); // Sets pages to be formatted as 3 columns, 5pt space between columns.
      w.Initialise( fs ); // Creates first page, ready to write text.

      // Optional style settings.
      w.Justify = 2; // Causes text to be justified.
      w.SetFont( w.Fonts[0], 9 ); // Sets font and font size.

      for ( int i = 0; i < 100; i += 1 ) 
        w.Txt( "Some arbitrary text which is long enough to demonstrate word wrapping. " );
      w.Finish();
    }
  }

  // Example with an image and embedded font ( subset ).
  public static void Example2() 
  {
    byte [] myImageBytes = Util.GetFile( @"c:\PdfFiles\666.png" );
    byte [] freeSansBytes = Util.GetFile( @"c:\PdfFiles\FreeSans.ttf" );

    using( IO.FileStream fs = IO.File.Create( "Example2.pdf") )
    {
      PdfWriter w = new Pdf.PdfWriter(); 
      w.Title = "Graphics and embedded font example";
      w.Initialise( fs );

      PdfImage myImage = ImageUtil.Add( w, myImageBytes ); 

      w.LineAdvance = myImage.Height / 2 + 10; // Make space for the image
      w.NewLine();
      w.LineAdvance = 15; // Restore LineAdvance to default value.
      w.CP.DrawImage( myImage, w.CP.X, w.CP.Y, 0.5f );

      PdfFont freeSans = new TrueTypeFont( "DJGTGD+Sans", freeSansBytes );
      w.SetFont( freeSans, 12 );
      w.Txt( "Hello world" );

      w.Finish();
    }
  }

  // PDF spec is at https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf
  // Minimum additional files: PdfPage.cs, Deflator.cs, PdfFont.cs, PdfMetric.cs.
  // Other files: PdfTrueType.cs, TrueType.cs, PdfPng.cs, Inflator.cs, PDfOther.cs, Util.cs, Pdfwriter2.cs.

  public void SetColumns( int n, float colSpace )
  { 
    Columns = n; 
    ColSpace = colSpace;
    LineLength = ( ( PageLayout.Width + colSpace - PageLayout.MarginRight - PageLayout.MarginLeft ) / n ) - colSpace;
  }

  public void Initialise( IO.Stream os ) 
  { 
    OS = os; 
    Put( "%PDF-1.4\n" ); 
    if ( CP == null ) 
    {
      if ( Fonts == null ) Fonts = StandardFontFamily.Helvetica();
      if ( _Font == null ) SetFont( Fonts[0], _FontSize );
      NewPage0();  
    }   
  }

  // Basic functions.
  public void Txt( String s ) {  Txt( s,0,s.Length ); } // Write justified text, word-wrapping to new line or page as required.
  public void NewLine() { FlushWord(); FinishLine( false ); } // Force a new line.
  public void NewPage() { NewLine(); NewPage0(); } // Force a new page.

  // Functions to adjust text style.
  public void SetFont( PdfFont f, int fontSize ) { Word.Font( f, fontSize ); _Font = f; _FontSize = fontSize; }
  public void SetSuper( int x ) { Word.Super( x ); _Super = x; }
  public void SetColor( String color ) { Word.Color( color ); }
  public void SetOther( String other ) { Word.Other( other ); }

  // Properties.
  public PdfFont Font{ get{ return _Font; } }
  public int FontSize{ get{ return _FontSize; } }
  public int Super{ get{ return _Super; } }
  public bool PartialLine{ get{ return WordCharCount > 0 || LineCharCount > 0; } }

  // Public fields.

  public String Title; // Assign a string to set the PDF title.

  // Page parameters
  public PageLayout PageLayout = new PageLayout( 595, 842, 36 ); // Default is A4, margin 36 pt.
  public PdfPage CP; // Current page, see PdfPage.cs for interface.

  // Line parameters ( in pt ).
  public float LineLength = 523, LineAdvance=15, LineMarginBefore=0;

  public FontFamily Fonts;

  // Line justification parameter.
  public int Justify=0; // Justify values are 0=right ragged, 1=center, 2=justifed.

  // Streams, Lists and Buffers
  public IO.Stream OS; // Final output stream.
  public long OS_Total = 0; // Total bytes written to OS ( for xref table ), must be updated if writing direct to OS.
  public Generic.List<PdfPage> Pages = new Generic.List<PdfPage>();
  public Generic.List<DynObj> DynObjs = new Generic.List<DynObj>();
  public Generic.List<long> Xref = new Generic.List<long>();

  // Compression option
  public bool Compress = true; // Set to false to make PDF easier to examine when testing or if compression not wanted.

  // Private fields.

  private PdfFont _Font; 
  private int _FontSize=12, _Super;

  private WordBuffer Word = new WordBuffer();
  private LineBuffer Line = new LineBuffer();

  // Word and Line state, used to calculate line justification and word wrapping.
  private float LinePos, SpacePos, ColSpace;
  private int SpaceCount, WordCharCount, LineCharCount, Columns = 1, CurColumn = 0;
  private bool FirstLine;

  // End fields.

  public void InitFont( PdfFont f ) { f.GetObj( this ); } // Only needs to be called if a page font is set directly.

  public virtual void NewColumn()
  {
    if ( CurColumn+1 < Columns )
    {
      LineMarginBefore += LineLength + ColSpace;
      FirstLine = true;
      CurColumn += 1;
    }
    else
    {
      NewPage0();
    }
  }

  public void NewPage0() // Start a new page ( without flushing word buffer, so current word can be carried over to next page ).
  { 
    PdfPage old = CP, p = new PdfPage();
    p.Layout = PageLayout;
    Pages.Add( p ); p.Number = Pages.Count; CP = p; 
    FirstLine = true; LinePos = 0; SpaceCount = 0; LineCharCount = 0;
    CurColumn = 0; LineMarginBefore = 0;
    StartPage();
    CP.InitTxtFrom( old ); 
  }

  private void FinishLine( bool wrap ) // Writes the line buffer to a page.
  {
    float space = LineLength - LinePos; 
    if ( wrap && SpaceCount > 0 ) space += ( LinePos - SpacePos );
    float centerjustify = Justify == 1 ? space / 2 : 0; // Center justification
    int lineCharCount = LineCharCount;

    // GetSpace if needed.
    if ( !FirstLine && CP.Y - LineAdvance < CP.Layout.MarginBottom ) NewColumn();

    if ( FirstLine ) 
    { 
      CP.Goto( centerjustify + CP.Layout.MarginLeft + LineMarginBefore, CP.Layout.Height - CP.Layout.MarginTop - LineAdvance ); 
      FirstLine = false; 
    }
    else 
    {
      CP.Td( centerjustify + CP.Layout.MarginLeft + LineMarginBefore - CP.X, -LineAdvance );
    }
    CP.SetCharSpacing( wrap && Justify == 2 ? space / lineCharCount : 0 );
    Line.Flush( CP );
    LinePos = 0; SpaceCount = 0; LineCharCount = 0;
  }

  private void FlushWord() { Word.Flush( Line ); LineCharCount += WordCharCount; WordCharCount = 0; } 

  private void WordAdd( String s, int start, int end ) // Append part of s to word buffer.
  { if ( start >= end ) return; Word.Str( s, start, end ); } 

  public void Txt( String s, int start, int end ) // Writes text word-wrapping to new line or page as required.
  {
    InitFont( _Font );
    int i = start;
    while ( i < end ) 
    {
      char c = s[i]; int uc = System.Char.IsSurrogate( c ) ? char.ConvertToUtf32( s, i ) : c;

      float cwidth = _Font.Width( uc, _FontSize );
      if ( LinePos + cwidth > LineLength || c == '\n' ) 
      {
        float carry = 0; // Amount carried to next line.
        if ( SpaceCount > 0 && c != '\n' ) 
        {
          carry = LinePos - SpacePos; // Word wrap, current word is written to next line.
        }
        else
        {
          // No word wrap, flush the word buffer.
          WordAdd( s, start, i ); start = i; FlushWord();
        }     
        FinishLine( c != '\n' ); 
        LinePos = carry;
      }
      LinePos += cwidth;
      i += 1; 
      if ( c != '\n' ) WordCharCount += 1;
      if ( c == ' ' ) 
      {
        WordAdd( s,start,i ); start = i; FlushWord();
        SpacePos = LinePos; SpaceCount += 1;
      }
      else if ( System.Char.IsSurrogate( c ) ) i += 1; // Skip surrogate pair char
    }   
    WordAdd( s, start, end );
  }

  public virtual void StartPage() {} // Can be over-ridden to initialise the page ( e.g. set a background image, draw a border ) .
  public virtual void FinishPage() {} // Can be over-ridden to finalise the page ( e.g. write a page number ) .
  public virtual int WritePages(){ return PdfPage.WritePages( this, Pages ); } 
  public virtual int WriteCatalog( int pagesobj ){ return PutObj( "<</Type/Catalog/Pages " + pagesobj + " 0 R>>" ); }

  public virtual int WriteInfo()
  {
    if ( Title != null )
    {
      int result = StartObj();
      Put( "<</Title" );
      PutStr( Title );
      Put ( ">>" );
      EndObj();
      return result;
    }
    return 0;
  }

  public virtual void Finish() 
  {
    if ( PartialLine ) NewLine();
    int catObj = WriteCatalog( WritePages() );
    int infoObj = WriteInfo();
    foreach( DynObj x in DynObjs ) x.WriteTo( this );
    long startxref = OS_Total; int xc = Xref.Count + 1;
    Put( "xref\n0 " + xc + "\n0000000000 65535 f\n" );
    for ( int i=0; i<Xref.Count; i += 1 ) Put( Xref[i].ToString( "D10" ) + " 00000 n\n" );
    Put( "trailer\n<</Size " + xc + "/Root " + catObj + " 0 R" 
      + ( infoObj == 0 ? "" : "/Info " + infoObj )
      + " 0 R" + ">>\nstartxref\n" + startxref + "\n%%EOF\n" );
  }

  // Low level functions for PDF creation.

  public void Put( byte b ) { OS.WriteByte( b ); OS_Total += 1; }

  public void Put( byte [] b ) { OS.Write( b, 0, b.Length ); OS_Total += b.Length; }

  public void Put( string s ) 
  { for ( int i=0; i < s.Length; i += 1 ) OS.WriteByte( ( byte ) s[i] ); OS_Total += s.Length; }

  public void PutStrByte( byte b )
  { if ( b == '(' || b == '\\' || b == ')' )
      Put( ( byte ) '\\' );
    if ( b == 13 )
      Put( @"\015" ); // Octal escape must be used for 13, see spec, bottom of page 15.
    else
      Put( b );
  }

  public static bool IsAscii( String s )
  {
    for ( int i = 0; i < s.Length; i += 1 ) if ( s[i] > 127 ) return false;
    return true;
  }

  public void PutStr( String s )
  {
    Put( (byte) '(' );
    if ( IsAscii (s) )
    {
      for ( int i=0; i < s.Length; i += 1 ) PutStrByte( (byte) s[i] );
    }
    else
    {
      Put( 254 ); Put( 255 ); // Byte order marker
      System.Text.Encoding enc = System.Text.Encoding.BigEndianUnicode;
      byte [] b = enc.GetBytes( s );
      for ( int i = 0; i < b.Length; i += 1 ) PutStrByte( b[i] );
    }
    Put( (byte) ')' );
  }

  public int AllocObj() { Xref.Add( 0 ); return Xref.Count; }

  public void AllocDynObj( DynObj x ) { if ( x.Obj == 0 ) { x.Obj = AllocObj();  DynObjs.Add( x ); } }

  public void StartObj( int ObjNum ) { Xref[ ObjNum-1 ] = OS_Total; Put( ObjNum + " 0 obj\n" ); }    

  public void EndObj() { Put( "\nendobj\n" ); }

  public int StartObj() { int obj = AllocObj(); StartObj( obj ); return obj; }

  public int PutObj( string s ) { int obj = StartObj(); Put( s ); EndObj(); return obj;  }

  // Compression functions

  public int PutStream( byte [] data ) 
  {
    int result = StartObj();
    Put( "<<" );
    if ( Compress ) 
    {
      Put( "/Filter/FlateDecode" );
      #if ( UseZLib ) 
      { 
        data = Deflate( data );
        Put( "/Length " + data.Length + ">>stream\n" );
        Put( data );
      } 
      #else
      {
        MemoryBitStream bb = new MemoryBitStream();
        Deflator.Deflate( data, bb, 1 );
        int clen = bb.ByteSize();
        Put( "/Length " + clen + ">>stream\n" );
        bb.CopyTo( OS );
        OS_Total += clen;
      }
      #endif
    }
    else 
    {
      Put( "/Length " + data.Length + ">>stream\n" );      
      Put( data );
    } 
    Put( "\nendstream" );
    EndObj(); 
    return result;   
  }

  public static byte [] Deflate( byte [] data ) 
  {
    #if ( UseZLib ) 
    IO.MemoryStream cs = new IO.MemoryStream();
    Zlib.ZDeflaterOutputStream zip = new Zlib.ZDeflaterOutputStream( cs );
    zip.Write( data, 0, data.Length ); 
    zip.Finish();
    return cs.ToArray();
    #else 
    MemoryBitStream bb = new MemoryBitStream();
    Deflator.Deflate( data, bb, 1 );
    return bb.ToArray();
    #endif
  }

  // WordBuffer and LineBuffer are used to implement text justification / line wrapping.

  private struct TextElem { public int Kind; public System.Object X; public int I1, I2; }

  private class WordBuffer : Generic.List<TextElem>
  {
    public void Str( String x, int i1, int i2 ) { this.Add( new TextElem{ Kind=0, X = x, I1 = i1, I2 = i2 } ); }
    public void Font( PdfFont x, int i1 ) {  this.Add( new TextElem{ Kind=1, X = x, I1 = i1 } ); }
    public void Super( int i1 ) { this.Add( new TextElem{ Kind=2, I1 = i1 } ); }
    public void Color( String x ) { this.Add( new TextElem{ Kind=3, X = x } ); }
    public void Other( String x ) { this.Add( new TextElem{ Kind=4, X = x } ); }
    public void Flush( LineBuffer b ) { foreach ( TextElem e in this ) b.Add( e ); Clear(); }
  }

  private class LineBuffer : Generic.List<TextElem>
  {
    public void Flush( PdfPage p ) 
    {
      foreach ( TextElem e in this ) 
      {
        switch ( e.Kind ) 
        {
          case 0: p.Txt( ( String ) e.X, e.I1, e.I2 ); break;
          case 1: p.SetFont( ( PdfFont ) e.X, e.I1 ); break;
          case 2: p.SetSuper( e.I1 ); break;
          case 3: p.SetColor( ( String ) e.X ); break;
          case 4: p.SetOther( ( String ) e.X ); break;
        }
      }
      Clear();
    }
  }

} // End class PdfWriter

} // namespace
```

Comment: Not strictly on-topic, but I'm wondering if you would mind making `Util.cs` available in the github repo? I've had to dip into PDF now and then, and I've really enjoyed looking through your questioned lately, but I'm too lazy to second guess the implementations of the utility methods.

Comment: @VisualMelon Sure, that was an oversight, I have now uploaded Util.cs

Answer (score 7):

Given that the `PdfWriter` holds a reference to an `IDisposable` resource (the `Stream`), it's good practice to implement `IDisposable`. Note that Stream is a special case of rule [CA2213](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/ca2213-disposable-fields-should-be-disposed?view=vs-2019).

I've also noticed that all of your examples call both `Initialise` and `Finish`. If that's the case, I'd argue for a factory method to create the writer and call `Finish` within the `Dispose` method of `PdfWriter`. That means your usage could become:

```
using (IO.FileStream fs = IO.File.Create("Example1.pdf"))
using (PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.Create(fs, new PdfWriterOptions 
                                               { 
                                                   Fonts = Pdf.StandardFontFamily.Times() 
                                               }))
{
    // The actual writing.
}
```

That saves the consumer from having to remember to call two methods every time they use the class.